# Converting directory full of h264 to images

Tags: video, ffmpeg, conversion, mp4, h264

first time here. Please be gentle. let me know what I missed out on and I will correct it.

my question is similar to this. So, I am hoping to get an answer for my specific query too.

[How can I convert .264 file to .mp4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690015/how-can-i-convert-264-file-to-mp4)

I have an entire directory with frames in .h264 format. These are generated from WebRTC for a single video.

I am able to convert the very first frame to image. However, when I am trying it for the subsequent frames, I am getting an error with ffmpeg. I am assuming there might be some dependency on the prior frames because of which I am getting this error.

How can I convert all the frames in that directory to images (jpeg or png)

Comment: Can you provide a link to one of the h264 input files?

Comment: Here's the link with sample files: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1oWpgRn7oAZLbIZ1nlFL5zhweNX4yK3FO?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

Typical H.264 frames are interdependent, so most frames can't be decoded individually.

Use `cat` to combine them all and pipe to `ffmpeg`:

```
cat *.h264 | ffmpeg -i - frame-%04d.png
```

Comment: Thank a ton. This worked for me.

Comment: Any chance you know the reason on how the quality of the same can be increased? Currently, I am getting the entire directory converted to images but the quality of most of the images is not that great. Currently, I am trying to change frame rates to see if something improves.

Comment: @HarshSolanki The input `frame-0001.h264` to `frame-0004.h264` have bad quality, so therefore the output PNG will also have bad quality for those 4 frames. Check the later frames and they should look better. Nothing you can do about it except to re-generate the h264 frames with a higher quality. Frame rate is meaningless when extracting individual images, so you do not need to change frame rate.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/).

```
$ HandBrakeCLI -Z Universal -i myinputfile -o myoutputfile
```

I found it [here](https://exceptionshub.com/convert-a-video-to-mp4-h-264aac-with-ffmpeg.html). Maybe it'll help.

And pleases also provide the error message, so we can help you more effectively.

Comment: The error is mentioned in the below link:https://docs.google.com/document/d/1__F9ZfP4qdr_yXf52zWTNZiZDfwZCevhJXUbrRtfAGc/edit?usp=sharing